# How to identify two identical nohup commands?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nohup

I have two websites using the Laravel framework. I need to use a command to process queues. For that I use nohup.

However I need to run two identical nohup commands to make it run in the background for the two different websites. The problem is that sometimes I need to stop only one command for maintenance. How do I identify which nohup command belongs to a particular website ? Can I use a name identifier in the nohup command ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use php's `-E` cli argument, which lets you specify code to execute "after" the rest of the script completes, and this extra code could be just a PHP comment, allowing you to embed ID information:

```
sudo nohup php -E '//job #x' artisan etc...
                   ^^^^^^^^---raw php code, no <?..?> required
```

Since it's just a comment, it won't actually DO anything, and you can format the comment to contain whatever ID information you want.

Comment: Thank you, that will do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

Witch `$!` you can get the PID of the last background process. Save it to a file like `echo $! > processA.pid` and then use that PID to stop the desired process.